# How to add dynamic fields on wordpress custom post type page in admin section

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, input

I need to add dynamic fields with title and description for post in admin section. I want to add these fields dynamically on click add new title and description. I want to save them in database and then i need to display on front page post details page. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ACF plugin to add multiple custom fields to your post using this plugin. 
  Please see this [LINK](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started-with-acf/)

You can read its document here is the [LINK](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: But with ACF I have to define all the fields in advance. I wanted to add dynamically on the post page.

Comment: @sonikakanda can you please tell me which type of dynamic fields?

Comment: I need multiple fields dynamically one for the title and another for description. Or anything like I can create multiple sub posts with main post.